GET Issues from Autodesk Construction Cloud APIs
We have ecountered problem while receiving response to GET issue request. JSON file does not contain position data for TwoDPushpin location. It is stored in Body in: results - linkedDocuments - details - position (x, y, z). While in old BIM360 it returns "position": {"x": -35.238098787487104,"y": 87.2047348022461,"z": -11.452384532007851}, in new ACC it returns "position": {}. We tested it on multiple documents the issue persists on each of them. Please provide solution hot to retrieve linked document issue pushpin position in ACC.
ACC api docs link
We compared the following APIs:

BIM360: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v2/containers/:containerId/issues

response:
{
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "type": "TwoDVectorPushpin",
      "urn": "",
      "createdBy": "",
      "createdAt": "2024-02-22T08:45:15.820Z",
      "createdAtVersion": 1,
      "closedBy": null,
      "closedAt": null,
      "closedAtVersion": null,
      "details": {
        "viewable": {...},
        "position": {
          "x": -138.13512638138647,
          "y": -111.15485659241676,
          "z": 43.54259595148501
        },
      ...
}


ACC: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/issues/v1/projects/:projectId/issues

response:
{
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "type": "TwoDRasterPushpin",
      "urn": "",
      "createdBy": null,
      "createdAt": "2024-05-02T06:58:27.331Z",
      "createdAtVersion": 1,
      "closedBy": null,
      "closedAt": null,
      "closedAtVersion": null,
      "details": {
        "viewable": {
          "id": "",
          "viewableId": "3",
          "guid": "",
          "name": "(3)",
          "is3D": false
        },
        "position": {},
        ...
}


Note that this endpoint is not compatible with BIM 360 projects.

Yes, of course. We use the ACC API only for ACC projects.

Yes, this is a known ACC limitation on issues. ACC only supports pushpin position for TwoDVectorPushpin (3D models) in directly linkedDocuments only unlike BIM360 that supports both TwoDVectorPushpin (3D models) and TwoDRasterPushpin (2D sheets and views).
There is a roadmap to improve the ACC issues to match each feature in BIM360 over a time but for now this coordinates position is not supported for TwoDRasterPushpin models

Thank you for the information!
